# Data Viewer for AppEngine development server

Tags: java, database, google-app-engine, testing

The Google AppEngine [development server](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/devserver.html) simulates Google's backend database with an embedded database. It creates a file on you local disk that you can delete to clear the DB.
Is there a tool that allows to browse and edit this data, similar to the Data Viewer that you get for deployed applications?

**Clarification**: I am asking about the Java toolkit, not the Python one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Finally, data viewer comes with Google App Engine Java SDK version 1.2.2.
It can be accessed at:

http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin

or

http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin

The same link as in Python version.

Answer (score 4):

On my system (sdk 1.2.8 I think) the dev server runs on port 8888. So the data viewer is at http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin

Answer (score 1):

You can find it at http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin. Looks bit different, but provides the same functionality (apart of [some bugs](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=502)).

But in the light of OP question amendment this answer is not relevant anymore.

Comment: Are you sure that is not just for the Python version?